Let T be a tree with at least 3 vertices of degree 1. Prove that T contains at least one vertex with a degree of at least 3.
Let $T$ be a tree with at least 3 vertices of degree 1. Prove that $T$ contains at least one vertex of degree at least 3.
I attempted a proof, but I am not sure if it is correct or if the phrasing is appropriate.
Here is my reasoning:
Let us denote these three leaves by  $u$,  $v$, and $w$. Consider the longest possible path in the tree from $ u $ to $ v $, and from $ u $ to $ w $.
These two paths must start the same way, meaning the first $ k $ vertices in both paths are the same. The $ k $-th vertex is the point where the two paths diverge, and it is precisely this vertex that must have a degree of at least 3.
If all vertices in the path from $ u $ to $ v $, for example, had a degree of 2 or less, then this path would form a simple chain. However, if this were the case, it would exclude $ w $ from being part of the tree. This would contradict the assumption that $ T $ is a tree (trees are connected graphs).
This is my reasoning. I wonder if it is correct and if it could be phrased in a more rigorous or mathematical manner. Thank you.

It's fine but your doing too much, it's good practice to only include what is necessary ie: Consider a path P from u to v, any additional vertex shares an edge with an interior vertex in P. However P only has 2 vertices of degree 1 hence w is not in P.

@tom What would that be?

If there existed two (or more) distinct paths between any pair of vertices, then there would exist (at least) a cycle, so the graph wouldn’t be a tree.

Suppose on the contrary $T$ contains only vertices with degree $1$ or $2$. Assume that there are $k_1(\geq 3)$ vertices with degree $1$ and $k_2$ vertices with degree $2$. Then by the handshaking lemma, $$2k_2+k_1=2E.$$ Since $T$ is a tree, $k_1+k_2-1=E$. Thus, $k_2+1=E$ and we get $$k_1=2,$$ which is a contradiction.

I can see why this works but it is not intuitive at all. I prefer my proof.
